Inhomegenous helmholtz in equation in 2D
Consider the 2d Dirichlet inhomogenous helmholtz BVP,
$\Delta v+kv =f \quad in~~\Omega,$
$v=h \quad on~~ \partial \Omega,$
Where $k$ is a constant. It is said that the solution of the BVP is
(i) unique if  $k\leq 0,$
(ii)Not unique if $k>0.$
Is this true because in (i) the characteristics polynomial of the homogenous equation is real valued i.e $r=\pm \sqrt{k}$      and in
(ii)  because the characteristics polynomial is imaginary i.e $r=\pm i\sqrt{k}$ ?
